# React useState empty array type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
interface Crumb {
  title: string;
  url: string;
}
interface Crumbies {
  crumbsArray: Crumb[];
}


// component
const [breadcrumbs, setBreadcrumbs] = useState<Crumbies>([]);
```

I'm getting an error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'never[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Crumbies | (() => Crumbies)'.   Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type '() => Crumbies'.     Type 'never[]' provides no match for the signature '(): Crumbies'.
```

How to provide a correct typings for an empty array in `useState` hook?

**UPDATE 1**

```
const Breadcrumbs: React.FC<Crumbies> = ({ crumbsArray }) => {}
```

That's why i've created another interface `Crumbies` to wrap `Crumb`. Is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The interface called Crumbies requires you to pass an object with a field crumbsArray:

```
const [breadcrumbs, setBreadcrumbs] = useState<Crumbies>({crumbsArray: []});
```

If you want to simply have an array of Crumb you don't need to create a new interface, you can simply do it in useState:

```
const [breadcrumbs, setBreadcrumbs] = useState<Crumb[]>([]);
```

This will initialise it with an empty array.

Comment: Thanks, with the first approach: `useState<Crumbies>({crumbsArray: []})` it would be impossible to use `setBreadcrumbs([])` since it would require an object, second approach works. I've created that additional interface Crumbies, because i needed to type my prop in a component, check my initial question, please.

Comment: I did. That's why I told you to use Crumb[] directly, no need to define a new interface just for an array.

Comment: Check UPDATE 1, please.

Comment: @AlexanderKim if you really really want to have a separate type for you array of Crumb you can do this:
```type Crumbies = Crumb[];```

But, as I said, you can just use Crumb[] directly, no need to have a separate type.

Comment: If the interface `Crumbies` is used for the component props, and `crumbsArray` is just a prop on the component, then sure, `Crumbies` works as the interface for the main component. Then, it looks like you're destructuring - good. But then you can just type your `useState` with `Crumb[]` as tudor suggested. `Crumbies` is for the entire component, `Crumb[]` is JUST for `useState`.